# How to make \include work with a quoted string path containing spaces?

Tags: include, input, paths

In Windows, `\input` can work with a quoted string path containing spaces, but `\include` cannot. How to fix it?

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

%\input works!
\input{"Contents/Installing and Configuring IIS 7/Configuring Security"}

%but \include does not work!
%\include{"Contents/Installing and Configuring IIS 7/Configuring Security"}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I'm not sure if that's really a solution. It was just a guess. So I will comment, instead. Do you get a "No file" error message? Could you try to enter "\includeonly{"Contents/Installing and Configuring IIS 7/Configuring Security"}" in the preamble first. Maybe "\include" would work after this.

Comment: @jimi, it did not and does not make sense. If it works like so, the other \include will be ignored, right?

Comment: @xport: sorry, that really did not make any sense. You may find the answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444385/include-a-tex-file-with-spaces-in-the-filename</a>. Someone else also had this problem a while back. It probably has something to do with the version of your distribution.

Comment: My knowledge of the include command is not that in-depth but as far as I understand, \includeonly reprocesses the specified file already called in the document through \include. I guess its only useful when you have multiple files and only want to work with a few. \include is never ignored, though, since that's what really makes the document. Check out the solutions from the link. If nothing works, fastest thing to do would be just to rename your file without spaces and you should be fine.

Comment: Does escaping the spaces work: `\include{file\ name}`

Comment: @Seamus, have you tried it?

Comment: @xport I can't: I don't have access to a windows computer

Comment: Your feelings about Windows seems sort of irrelevant here. If you mean that you need a solution that works for MiKTeX on Windows, that's what you should say.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `\space` within the file name, which works for me with `\include` on Windows:

```
\include{"Configuring\space Security"}
```

It works with paths and with file names. An .aux files with blanks in the file name would be produced, `\includeonly` works as well if `\space` is used too.

Comment: where do I insert \string in the path?

Comment: @xport: also for `\includeonly` use `\space`, `\string` is not required, I corrected that.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to protect the filename with an additional brace. On miktex/winxp this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\includeonly{{"test space"}}
\begin{document}
\include{{"test space"}}
\end{document}
```

But don't expect it to work on other systems too! If you need something reliable remove better the spaces.

Comment: can we substitute \input for \include with additional commands?

Comment: Well internally \include is \input with additional commands. So naturally you can replace it. But what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Ulrike, thanks first. I need a new \include-like inclusion command that can accept string path with spaces, of course.

Comment: I guessed that. But which features of \include do you actually need? And did you actually tried my solution? If yes why doesn't it help you.

Comment: @Ulrike, your solution did not work. I got nothing.

Comment: @xport: "I got nothing" doesn't give any information that'd be needed to figure out why it doesn't work for you. Did you get an error? Was there a message in the log? Something else?

Comment: @TH. : Sorry, I didn't read your comment. As I already have the solution from Stefan, I am no longer interested to figure out the details pertaining to "I got nothing". :-)