# Inputting multiple files in LaTeX

Tags: input, automation

Suppose I have a directory containing a bunch of LaTeX source files, and I want to input all of them into a single main file. I could do this by saying

```
\input{dir/file1.tex}
\input{dir/file2.tex}
\input{dir/file3.tex}
...
```

Is there some way to input all of files in the directory "dir" using a single command? This is useful, for example, if I want to keep adding files to the directory "dir" but don't want to have to remember to add further \input commands to the main file.

Comment: This might be possible if TeX/LaTex had a system interface. Then one could query the directory for all files, and then programatically loop over all the files, calling \input on each one. But I don't know what the support for such things is. Wild suggestion - luatex?

Comment: This appears to be a near-duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder

Comment: And one of the answers uses Luatex, namely http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder/7662#7662

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My suggestion is to create one file with all the `\input` lines automatically and use `\input` to include this file (and hence, all desired files) into your main document. The best way to keep everything up to date would be a Makefile. On a Unix system you can use this command line to create the file with the input lines:

```
ls dir/*.tex | awk '{printf "\\input{%s}\n", $1}' > inputs.tex
```

You would only update `inputs.tex` once in a while (or automatically) but always use `\input{inputs.tex}` in your main document. The beauty of using `ls` (or `find`) is that you can combine naming some files explicitly and others using shell (glob) patterns to control what files are included in what order.

#### Makefile

The GNU Make Makefile rule to do this automatically would look like this:

```
.PHONY: all
all:   inputs.tex

inputs.tex: $(wildcard dir/*.tex)
  ls dir/*.tex | awk '{printf "\\input{%s}\n", $$1}' > inputs.tex
```

A call to `make` would trigger updating the `all` target, which in turn would update `inputs.tex` if any of the included TeX files has changed or a new one was added.

#### Shell Escapes

Reading about shell escapes in PDFLaTeX in the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder) mentioned by [Faheem Mitha](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3406/faheem-mitha), here is another idea: one could also execute the command line mentioned above from within the LaTeX source file and read `\input{inputs.tex}` after that. However, I haven't tried this.

Comment: Parsing the output of ls like this is very bad. It will break if a filename contains e.g., a space! In bash it can be handled very neatly with a loop: { shopt -s nullglob; for file in dir/*.tex; do echo "\\input{$file}"; done; } > inputs.tex. Otherwise it can be handled with make: Replace the outrageous line with, e.g.: @{ $(foreach file,$(wildcard dir/*.tex),echo "\input{$(file)}";) } > inputs.tex

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: `\input` has trouble with spaces in file names. So you would have to do more -- see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7010/input-can-work-with-quoted-string-path-containing-spaces-but-include-cannot-h). I intended my answer more as a general idea rather than a perfect solution.

Comment: @ChristianLindig I had to change your $1 to $$1 in order for make to not think that the $1 is a variable that needs expansion.

Comment: @g33kz0r You are right, it must be `$$1` in the Makefile. Fixed it.

Answer (score 22):

You could use package [`bashful`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bashful) to do it from within LaTeX, e.g., using gniourf_gniourf  suggestion, you would write

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{bashful}
\begin{document}
\bash[stdoutFile=inputs.tex]
{ shopt -s nullglob; for file in dir/*.tex; do echo "\\input{$file}"; done; } 
\END
\input{inputs.tex}
\end{document}
```