# How to include all files in a directory in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, include, directory

I need to include a large number of files in my ConTeXt document:

```
\starttext

    \include file1
    \include file2
    \include file3
    \include file4
    \include file5

\stoptext
```

They are all generated by a script, so I don't know how many files there are beforehand are, but they must be included in alpha-numerical order, not randomly.

I found this [Including all files within a directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38571/including-all-files-within-a-directory), [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder), and many other LaTeX solutions, but cannot find a solution in ConTeXt, and found nothing in the manuals.

How can I include all of the files found in a folder?

Comment: Have you tried making a call from Lua? It should be straightforward…

Comment: It might be easier if the script generating the file-names were rewritten so as to output names in the style *file 001, file002 … file999*. That way, you don't have to worry about the difference between a lexical sort (10 before 9) and a numerical sort (09 before 10). On the other hand, if someone thinks of a solution using ConTeXt's `\dorecurse` or `\dostepwiserecurse` you would be OK without the zero-padding. The most relevant wiki pages seem to be [this one](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Write18) and [this one.](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Executesystemcommand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the shell and all sorts of platform-dependent tools, you can use the builtin [Lua Filesystem library](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html) of LuaTeX to traverse all files in the current directory.  When iterating I test whether the element has the `.tex` extension and that it actually is a file and then append it to the list of files.  The list is then sorted inplace using a lexical sort by `table.sort`.  In the document we can then loop over list of files and call `context.input` for each of them.

```
\startluacode
```

```lua
local files = {}

for file in lfs.dir(lfs.currentdir()) do
    if file:match("%.tex$") and lfs.attributes(file, "mode") == "file" then
        files[#files + 1] = file
    end
end

table.sort(files)
```

```
\stopluacode

\starttext

\startluacode
```

```lua
for _, file in ipairs(files) do
    context.input(file)
end
```

```
\stopluacode

\stoptext
```

Comment: Does this work if the file before file10.tex is called file9.tex, or does it have to be called file09.tex?

Comment: @TEV Of course it works, but I presume you are asking about the ordering.  As stated in my answer, `table.sort` performs lexical ordering, i.e. `file10.tex` will appear *before* `file9.tex`.  But you can provide your own comparison function as a second argument to `table.sort`.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal working example with names *exactly* as specified by you:

```
\starttext
\directlua 0 { os.execute("ls | sed -n '/^file[0-9][0-9]*$/s/^file//p' | sort -n | sed 's/.*/\\\\input file&/' > ListOfFiles.tmp") }

\input{ListOfFiles.tmp}
\stoptext
```

I'm not saying this is a *good* example, just a *working* example. Yes, it really does use a quadruple backslash to get a single backslash into the temporary file. The embedded sed scripts become only slightly more complicated if your files have names like *file1.txt*, *file2.txt*. Something like this:

```
\starttext
\directlua 0 { os.execute("ls | sed -n 's/^file\\([0-9][0-9]*\\)\\.txt$/\\1/p' | sort -n | sed 's/.*/\\\\input file&.txt/' > ListOfFiles.tmp") }

\input{ListOfFiles.tmp}
\stoptext
```

If you're using Windows, I guess you would have to run ConTeXt from something like Cygwin or Msys to make this monstrosity work. Or rewrite it it pure lua that doesn't use *sh*, *ls*, *sed* & *sort*.