# Command for including all .tex files from a folder into the current file

Tags: overleaf, include, import

[image]

What command can I write in `main.tex` as shorthand for "include all `.tex` files from a given folder". So I don't have to write a lot of `\include{}` commands for each file like

```
\include{sections/introduction.tex}
\include{sections/section2.tex}
// And so on...
```

### **EDIT: MY SOLUTION**

```latex
\begin{document}

\foreach \folder in {sections, images} {%    
    \foreach \i in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ..., 19} {%
        \edef\FileName{\folder/\i}%     The % here are necessary to eliminate any
        \IfFileExists{\FileName}{%      spurious spaces that may get inserted
           \input{\FileName}%           at these points
        }
    }
}

\end{document}
```

Reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38576/151373

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38571/including-all-files-within-a-directory

Comment: You either need to enable `-shell-escape` and use a shell command to get a list of the files or you need to list them manually. TeX cannot “find files”, it can only look them up by name.