# Inputting files alphabetically

Tags: input, automation

I am creating an anthology of poems and songs, and have a main file where I am using `\input` to insert separates TeX files which contain the poems.

I was wondering if there was a simpler way of inserting all of the files in alphabetical order based on filename instead of a separate `\input` for each file?

Could anybody help?

---

Thank you to for pointing me in the direction of the other questions - they didn't come up when I googled my queries. I am trying to adapt the code in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder) but I am getting 2 errors from it. My code is as follows at the moment

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\makeatletter%
\def \app@exe {\immediate\write18}

\def \inputAllFiles [#1]{%
  \app@exe{cmd /c dir /b *.tex > \jobname.tmp}
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tmp}{}{}
  \AtEndOfDocument{\app@exe{rm -f #1/\jobname.tmp}}}
\makeatother%

\begin{document}

\inputAllFiles{.}

\end{document}
```

The errors messages I am getting are both on the line with the `\inputAllFiles` command and say: `Use of \inputAllFiles doesn't match its definition` and `Too many }'s`.

I have tried fiddling around with the code, but noting I seem to do helps. Could anybody help to see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Related: [Inputting multiple files in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13921/5764)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Related: [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder).  The accepted answer here is probably already in alphabetical order, but if not it should be easily sorted.

Comment: Why do you add spaces and brackets in the code copied from linked answer?

Comment: The original code wasn't being recognised at all, so I looked up the `\def` command online and that seemed to be the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a script in whatever language is handy, which takes the file listing and massages it into (the guts of) the file doing the including.

I'm sure there is a LaTeX way of doing this, but in my extremely humble opinion this kind of solution is doable (and understandable) by mere mortals like myself.