# How to include all bibfiles in a directory?

Tags: biblatex, resources

I managed to add all bibfiles in a `bib/` directory to my default resource list by using `\write18` and `pdflatex -shell-escape`.

Is there a less cumbersome way to do add all bibfiles in a directory to the resource list?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

  \begin{filecontents}{bib/1.bib}
   @book{key1, title="title1", author="author1", year="2001"}
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{filecontents}{bib/2.bib}
   @book{key2, title="title2", author="author2", year="2002"}
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{filecontents}{bib/3.bib}
   @book{key3, title="title3", author="author3", year="2003"}
  \end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\immediate\write18
{for i in bib/*; do echo "\string\\\string\\addbibresource\string{$i\string}"; done >bibresources.tex}

\input{bibresources}

\begin{document}
 \nocite{*}
 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: If that works for you (on my windows machine, I could not get the `echo` to work just now), I think that is a very good solution. And it is not very cumbersome in the end, do you think? Without `\write18`, LaTeX has no way of knowing about the files in the `./bib` folder without resorting to some way to scour the folder.

Comment: What I find really cumbersome is having to run `pdflatex` with a `-shell-escape` flag. Correct me if I'm wrong: not even `biblatex` itself would be able to list a `bib` directory for bibfiles if the user didn't pass `-shell-escape` to `pdflatex` ?

Comment: As far as I know (and I'm not one hundred percent firm on these TeX core questions) TeX can only find files it knows (of) by name, so it can search in the input paths or via `kpsewhich`. If you don't specify a name, we need a way to obtain the name and that is what we need the shell-escape for; you need access to the entire file system. See also [Inputting multiple files in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13921/35864), [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7653/35864).

Comment: Running `pdflatex` with `-shell-escape` does not appear more cumbersome that running it without (you could probably have your favourite editor create a new build tool with shell escape, or have a sot of shortcut in your command line). Fundamentally, `biblatex` cannot do more than LaTeX in finding files (it is a LaTeX package after all; if you leave out Biber, there could be a way using Biber, but that would then require - if at all possible - a much higher number of compiler passes.) I would like to mention though that there appears to be a LuaTeX solution.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the shell escape, because you can do it from the shell.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

  \begin{filecontents}{bib/1.bib}
   @book{key1, title="title1", author="author1", year="2001"}
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{filecontents}{bib/2.bib}
   @book{key2, title="title2", author="author2", year="2002"}
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{filecontents}{bib/3.bib}
   @book{key3, title="title3", author="author3", year="2003"}
  \end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addbibresources}{m}
 {
  \clist_set:NV \l_tmpa_clist \bibresources
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
   {
    \addbibresource{#1/##1}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\addbibresources{bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If `rostov.tex` is the file, you can call the LaTeX run with

```
pdflatex "\def\bibresources{$(ls -m bib)}\input{rostov}"
```