# Multiple bibliographies when each child document has its own directory

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I'm using the [`chapterbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib) package for multiple bibliographies. I put the following two lines in the preamble.

```
\usepackage[square,numbers,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
```

Included chapter files with

```
\include{Chapter01}
```

and added the bibliography to the end of each chapter with

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
```

This works perfectly. But when I put each chapter in its own sub directory  and use `\input` rather than `\include` like this

```
\input{../101Chapter01/101Chapter01}
```

it produces the global bibliographies for each chapter. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is true. You have to use `\include` because it generates its own `.aux` file whereas `\input` does not. But what's the problem now? Why do you want to use `\input` instead of `\include`?

Comment: @Thorsten: Thanks for your comment. Actually I want to keep each chapter file in separate directory.

Comment: This is no problem. You can use it like this: `\include{path/to/my/file}`.

Comment: @Thorsten: Is this okay \include{D:/Path1 from/Path2 from/101Chapter01}? What about space in the path name? Thanks

Comment: I have never tried `\include` using spaces in paths. Maybe this works: `\include{"my path with spaces"/file}`. But I generally recommend you to avoid spaces in paths.

Comment: I have been trying to run the `chapterbib` package with child files in various subdirectories using `\include` and full paths suggested by Thornsten. However, I have been unsuccessful as I cannot create AUX files for the children by running BibTex on each child. `chapterbib` needs the AUX files to work. I've read that MikTeX security may be preventing related AUX files from being written in different directories (if I'm reading this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/how-can-i-include-the-file-somedir-file-tex-in-the-file-somedir-subdir-another/2214#2214 correctly).

Comment: @Thorsten Please convert your three comments to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Converted my comments to an answer as @lockstep requested)*

## Main question

This behavior is true. You have to use `\include` because it generates its own `.aux` file whereas `\input` does not.

There is no need to use `\input` when you want to use a path to another directory. This is also possible with `\include` (e.g. `\include{path/to/my/file}`).

## Referencing to the comments

The OP also asked another question in a comment. Because it's not part of the original question I will split this section from the main answer.

Referencing to your comment which contains another question about spaces in paths I can only make some **guesses**  because I have never tried to do so:

*Maybe* you could use `"` to hold the filename that contains spaces (e.g. `\include{"my path with spaces"/file}` or *maybe* `\include{"my path with spaces/file"}`). As I'm not sure about this I searched for related questions on tex.sx and found a promising answer by @Stefan Kottwitz ([How to make \include work with a quoted string path containing spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7345/3240)). There he suggests to use the `\space` command in those cases (e.g. `\include{"my\space path\space with\space spaces/file"}`).

But I generally recommend you to avoid spaces or special characters in paths because it *may*  also cause problems if you're using your files on different operating systems.