# What are the forbidden characters in file name with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, miktex, filesystem-access

I was wondering what are the forbidden characters in file name using XeLaTeX.

I know that the forbidden characters for Windows files are `\` `/` `?` `:` `*` `"` `>` `<` `|`

Also, I have found another character that is forbidden by XeLaTeX which is the apostrophe (`'`) because it generated an error.

Anyone knows if there's a list of forbidden characters?

**EDIT:**
I think my problem might be when I call the XeLaTeX in command line

`" -output-directory \"C:/Pdf\" \"C:/Pdf/Doe_John_BURCUS Gregoire (F) - 121217.tex\""`

MiKTeX doesn't recognize the file name. If I delete the parentheses, MiKTeX is able to generate the pdf.

Comment: may be related [Naming LaTeX files: best practice?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12174/15717)

Comment: Some characters may be disallowed by the OS; but, for instance, with appropriate quoting, I'm able to input files with all those characters in their name (not on Windows, I admit).

Comment: thanks for your responses, i have edited my question, maybe the source of the problem is my command line

Comment: I don't really know about Windows, but in general it's not a good idea to use file names with spaces in TeX; avoiding special characters is also good practice.

Comment: If i delete the parenthese, miktek is able to generate the pdf.

Comment: Please add the error message. But the way you posted it here, there is in my opinion another mistake: It should be `xelatex  -output-directory="C:/Pdf" "C:/Pdf/Doe_John_BURCUS Gregoire (F) - 121217.tex"`, intentionally written with the error causing parentheses to show my intention.

Comment: @Speravir Seems about right. Though, I find it _weird_ that the OP is calling XeLaTeX with all parameters wrapped inside `"`s (and did’t write the actual `xelatex` call).

Comment: Though I’m still convinced you used the `"` not correctly, I see now, that there is really a bug: The `xelatex` call strips the parentheses, so it will be searched for another file. – And you are lucky, if this **not** exists!

Comment: Bug filed under https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2203/ Therefore noone can help here and this question must be closed as “Too localized”.

Comment: [This discussion](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2009-December/015314.html) seems relevant.  It appears to be a "feature" of XeTeX that the parentheses have a special meaning, though I don't really understand why.  Also I think the question should be reopened as it would be useful to have a list of forbidden characters in file names.

Comment: @Speravir:  The fact that it's a bug doesn't mean the question should be closed; [see here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2622/questions-which-are-bug-reports/2625#2625)

Comment: related: [allowable filenames for source files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59367/14996)